# Javascript help (beginner)

Tags: javascript, html

I am a a beginner at JavaScript and was writing some video controls. When i open in chrome i get the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument.initialiseWebPage (VideoScript.js:26)"

The error points to the last line. Any ideas?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialiseWebPage);

function initialiseWebPage() {
  const myVideo = document.querySelector("video");
  myVideo.removeAttribute("controls");
  const playButton = document.getElementById("playPause");


  function PlayPause() {
    if (myVideo.paused === true) {
      myVideo.play();
      //
      playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
      myVideo.pause();
      playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
  }
  playButton.addEventListener("click", PlayPause);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MMU VIDEO</title>
  <script src="scripts/VideoScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1></h1>
  </header>

  <section id="videoContainer">
    <video width="640" height="360" poster="images/poster.jpg">
 <source src="Videos/mp4/MMU.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="Videos/webm/MMU.webm" type=video/webm">
 <p> Your browser does not support HTML5 video. You can download the video 
    file <a href="videos/mp4/MMU.mp4">here</a> instead.</p> 
 </video>

    <div id="VideoControls">
      <button type="button" id="PlayPause">Play</button>
    </div>
    <!-- </section> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your html? :)

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! it looks like the element with the ID `playPause` is not defined, could you please add your HTML to the question ?

Comment: When do you run your code? In the head, at the end of the body, or in a doc or window load call?

Comment: You will learn fast that with JavaScript various browsers have different implementations, so always test for a function being valid as with event listeners there are alternate versions...you can sometimes just check the browser name.

Comment: Your element has id "PlayPause" but you search for "playPause".

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an element like so:
`const playButton = document.getElementById("playPause");` Here you specify  id `playPause`, but your actual id is `PlayPause`. This is perhaps why `playButton` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

In your HTML, you are missing a quote and you're not closing the `source` tags, which are self-closing elements. They should look like this:

```
<source src="Videos/mp4/MMU.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="Videos/webm/MMU.webm" type="video/webm"/>
```

Secondly, you are attaching the event handler to the body **before** defining the function. This should work:

```
function initialiseWebPage()
{
  const myVideo = document.querySelector ( "video" );
  myVideo.removeAttribute( "controls" );
  const playButton = document.getElementById ("PlayPause");

    function PlayPause() {
    if (myVideo.paused === true) {
      myVideo.play();
      //
      playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
      myVideo.pause();
      playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
  }
  playButton.addEventListener("click", PlayPause);
}

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialiseWebPage);
```

As others have noted, you also have a capitalization error in your `PlayPause` selector.